# Codewars. Some tests are passed, but i need to get tests which outputs the following mistake: 3263 should equal -1

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x, digit

Can you explain it what problems are here? To my mind, this code is like a heap of crap but with the right solving. I beg your pardon for my english. 
the task of this kata:

Some numbers have funny properties. For example:

```
89 --> 8¹ + 9² = 89 * 1

695 --> 6² + 9³ + 5⁴= 1390 = 695 * 2

46288 --> 4³ + 6⁴+ 2⁵ + 8⁶ + 8⁷ = 2360688 = 46288 * 51
```

Given a positive integer n written as abcd... (a, b, c, d... being digits) and a positive integer p we want to find a positive integer k, if it exists, such as the sum of the digits of n taken to the successive powers of p is equal to k * n. In other words:

```
Is there an integer k such as : (a ^ p + b ^ (p+1) + c ^(p+2) + d ^ (p+3) + ...) = n * k
```

If it is the case we will return k, if not return -1.

Note: n, p will always be given as strictly positive integers.

`dig_pow(89, 1)` should return 1 since 8¹ + 9² = 89 = 89 * 1

`dig_pow(92, 1)` should return -1 since there is no k such as 9¹ + 2² equals 92 * k

`dig_pow(695, 2)` should return 2 since 6² + 9³ + 5⁴= 1390 = 695 * 2

`dig_pow(46288, 3)` should return 51 since 4³ + 6⁴+ 2⁵ + 8⁶ + 8⁷ = 2360688 = 46288 * 51

```
def dig_pow(n, p):
    if n > 0 and p > 0:
        b = []
        a = str(n)
        result = []
        for i in a:
            b.append(int(i))
            for x in b:
                if p != 1:
                    result.append(x ** p)
                    p += 1
                else:
                    result.append(x ** (p + 1))

        if int((sum(result)) / n) < 1:
            return -1
        elif int((sum(result)) / n) < 2:
            return 1
        else:
            return int((sum(result)) / n)
```

test results:

Test Passed

Test Passed

Test Passed

Test Passed

3263 should equal -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exact version of Python you're using. This following code are in Python 3. And if I get you correctly, the code can be as simple as

```
def dig_pow(n, p):
    assert n > 0 and p > 0
    digits = (int(i) for i in str(n)) # replaces your a,b part with generator
    result = 0 # you don't use result as a list, so an int suffice
    for x in digits: # why do you need if in the loop? (am I missing something?)
        result += x ** p
        p += 1

    if result % n: # you just test for divisibility
        return -1
    else:
        return result // n
```

The major problem is that, in your objective, you have only two option of returning, but you wrote `if elif else`, which is definitely unnecessary and leads to problems and bugs. The `%` is modulus operator.

Also, having an `if` and not returning anything in the other branch is often not a good idea (see the `assert` part). Of course, if you don't like it, just fall back to `if`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood all drawbacks of my code and fix it. But except the last moment... if result % n: return -1 What is the function of the modulus operator in this example? It cannot find the remainder? Is 'result' cannot be divided by 'n' and hence it outputs the 'return -1'?

Comment: Why it pass from 'if statement' to 'return -1' statement in some cases?

Comment: @OlegRadchenko, the % is the modulus operator, which computes the remainder of lhs // rhs. You can check the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex).

Comment: @OlegRadchenko Sorry I don't really get it. Did you just find a bug in the code? If the remainder is zero (implicit bool false), it will return the result, else it will return -1.

Comment: Oops exactly. My mistake. I misunderstood the terms of the task. I thought that i need to divide the result by n and then receive an integer. Approximately like this: (int(sum(result)) // n). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could work as well and I find it a little easier to read, however it can definitely be improved:

```
def dig_pow(n, p):
    value = 0
    for digit in str(n):
        value += int(digit)**p
        p += 1
    for k in range(1,value):
        if value/k == n:
        return k
    return -1
```

Comment: Please provide a little explanation; code-only answers, even when correct, don't do much to help the OP figure out what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this is some example simple example than using:

```
digits = (int(i) for i in str(n))
```

I'm opting to use this version since I am still a beginner which can be done with this alt way:

```
result = 0

for digits in str(n):
    #iterate through each digit from n
    # single of digits turn to int & power to p
    for number in digits: 
        result += int(number) ** p
        p += 1
```

as for the full solution, it goes like this:

```
def dig_pow(n, p):
    # example n = 123 , change it to string = 1, 2, 3
    # each string[] **p, and p iterate by 1
    # if n % p not equal to p  return - 1

result = 0

for digits in str(n):

    #iterate through each digit from n
    # single digit turn to int & power to p
    for number in digits: 
        result += int(number) ** p
        p += 1  
        
if result % n:
    return -1
else:
    return result // n
```